# Mock testing to pass a function reference in parameter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a function like in class A:

```
private async Task<T> Refresh(int a, string x)
{

// do something.. modify x
return x;
}
```

Now, this function is basically a parameter to another function in the same class A like.

```
classBobject.Get("somestring",(returnvalue) => Refresh(a,returnvalue));
```

My mock looks like :

```
classBmockObject.Setup(classAmock => classAmock.Get<T>("somestring",(returnvalue) => Refresh(a, returnvalue))).ReturnsAsync(someotherobject);
```

However, this requires me to create a new function called Refresh again in the test class.

Now I am not sure how do I write a mock unit test case to test the `b.get()` method. 
**How shall I pass the 3rd parameter without rewriting the function body again in the test class?**

Comment: Mocking, as un-due diligent as it is, generally involves databases and services.   If you are going to mock plain old methods you'll be there for quite a while not to mention any pass results prove nothing

Comment: Also, you don't appear to be 'await'ing the results

Comment: Moq 4.7 for .Net

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: In method `Refresh`, the identifyer `x` is a parameter of type `string`. Then how can you `return x;` when the return type is `Task<T>`.  And what is the definition of `T` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved this by passing below as 3rd param to the Get method.

```
It.IsAny <Func<T, Task<T>>
```

So, it looks like:

```
classBmockObject.Setup(classAmock => classAmock.Get<T>("somestring",It.IsAny <Func<T, Task<T>>())).ReturnsAsync(someotherobject);
```

Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a common base class to both the classes A and AMock.

This is usually useful if they should do the same thing, but also allows your tests to miss errors hidden by an error in the Refresh method, since your test is not independent from the code it is testing anymore.

Also, if the third listing is not in class A/AMock, you might just want to use `=> classAmock.Refresh(` instead of `=> Refresh(`, if the visibility allows this.